# Unable to update the `setState` inside `useEffect` conditionally

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

### Component For Either Creating Or Editing The User

A part of the code below where I am setting the `isActive` state conditionally inside `useEffect`

I am getting the other fields of `user_data` and successfully updating the `state`
but only `setIsActive` is not updating the `state`

```
function CreateUser() {

    const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState<boolean | undefined>();
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (params_user_id?.id != null) {
            const SINGLE_USER_URL = `users/${params_user_id.id}/edit`;
            const getSingleUser = async () => {
                const {data} = await axios.get(SINGLE_USER_URL)
                console.log(data)
                setIsActive(data.isactive)
                console.log('isactive', isActive)
            }
            getSingleUser();
        }
    }, [params_user_id])

    return (
        <>
     <Form.Check
          defaultChecked={isActive}
          className='mb-3'
          type='checkbox'
          id='active'
          onChange={e => setIsActive(!(isActive))}
          label='Active: Unselect for deleting accounts.'/> 
        </>
    )

}
```

**Form.Check** From `Bootstrap-React`

`When I hit the Edit page`

[image: Screen Shot of result page]

I did try many things like `ternary operator` etc
`checkBox` is not `checked` bcoz it's `undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the state in React acts like an async function.
Meaning that the when you set the state and put a `console.log` right after it, it will likely run before the state has actually finished updating.

Which is why we have `useEffect`, a built-in React hook that activates a callback when one of it's dependencies have changed.

In your case you're already using `useEffect` to update the state, but if you want to act upon that state change, or simply to log it's value, then you can use another separate `useEffect` for that purpose.

**Example:**

```js
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(isActive)
   // Whatever else we want to do after the state has been updated.
}, [isActive])
```

This `console.log` will run only after the state has finished changing and a render has occurred.

- Note: "isActive" in the example is interchangeable with whatever other state piece you're dealing with.

Check the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for more info about this.

---

#### Additional comments:

- Best to avoid using the loose `!=` to check for equality/inequality and opt for strict inequality check instead, i.e. - `!==`
  Loose inequality is seldom used, if ever, and could be a source for potential bugs.
- Perhaps it would better to avoid typing this as `boolean | undefined`.
  Unless justified, this sounds like another potential source for bugs.
  I would suggest relying on just `boolean` instead.

Comment: when I am submitting the `EDIT form` with the user who are `active` or simply `checked` the `checkbox` And I am console the `result` >> `data:
isActive: "I01\n"
reportingOfficer: "11"
userRole: "5"
username: "user_10"
[[Prototype]]: Object
message: "User Updated"
[[Prototype]]: Object`

Why I am getting `isActive`:`I01\n`  instead of `true`?

Comment: This is unrelated to your original issue. It's a different problem and should be a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can't get the state's updated value immediately after setting it because **[State Updates May Be Asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)**

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (params_user_id?.id != null) {
            const SINGLE_USER_URL = `users/${params_user_id.id}/edit`;
            const getSingleUser = async () => {
                const {data} = await axios.get(SINGLE_USER_URL)
                console.log(data)
                setIsActive(data.isactive)
                console.log('isactive', isActive) // <-- You can't get updated value immediately
            }
            getSingleUser();
        }
}, [params_user_id])
```

Change the type of `useState` to `boolean` only and set the default value to `false`.

```
const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState<boolean>(false);
```

Then, in `Form.Check`, update `onChange` to this:

```
 <Form.Check
      defaultChecked={isActive}
      className='mb-3'
      type='checkbox'
      id='active'
      onChange={() => setIsActive((preVal) => !preVal)}
      label='Active: Unselect for deleting accounts.'
  />
```